# showing empty tableview then load data from json then reload table view

Tags: swift, uitableview

My app doesn't work on the old iPad because the initial loading time is more than 20 secs. I currently have a tableview that loads data from json, the json takes a while to load (much slower on the older iPad)

My plan is to load an empty table view first and then load the json with a spinner by removing the load data call from viewWillAppear(), but where can I put the load data call? Putting the data call in the tableview delegate functions did not work, like numberOfSections because the view still waits for the data call before loading the table.

Is this possible?

Comment: Please include your current code in your question. The problem most probably is that you are loading the data synchronously and hence blocking the UI, but without seeing the code, it is hard to tell. You should load the data asynchronously. Is that JSON file stored on the device itself or downloaded from the web?

Comment: numberOfSections is not a good place to call you service. You need to place it in viewDidLoad. Use Alamofire https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire and load it asynchronously.

Comment: Any idea on where I should put the activity indicator while the data is loading in the other thread? Should i put the indicator in the main or the sub thread?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help, as the previous users mentions, using the dispatch async and calling table reload works.